# CORS problem when i use nginx on my server, but it completely fine when i try to fetch from the IP+Port

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, cors, rate-limiting

I face a problem with CORS when i try to fetch my server, it says 'has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource'

**BUT** only when i try to fetch it through nginx/myDNS(HTTPS). it's completely fine when i try to fetch it through the IP public+port (HTTP)

i enabled the cors from my backend already with HAPI

```
 routes: {
      cors: {
        origin: ['*'],
      },
    },
```

And sometimes it retrieves the data but it became a glitch, on the first load of the page cors error happens, but when i try to move to the other page it retrieves the Data, for example

[image: first time failed, but fine after]

And for example, i do run fetch for 3 destinations for 1 page (showcases, totalcards, and trades) the error happens first then i move to the other page which only fetch 1 destination it's fine, all good, but when i try to fetch (showcases, totalcards, and trades) again, the error happens like this

[image: glitch]

i try to enable the cors inside nginx, but it still not working, either it became multiple rules, or when i only enable it from nginx, the BE cors blocked error happen.

i've tried to enable cors both in my nodejs and nginx but it became a multiple rules problem, but when i only apply it into only nginx CORS i can't even retrieve the data from my BE and when i only apply it inside my nodejs, it sometimes glitch, what should i do to fix this error? i hosted it in AWS-Ec2

Comment: Has this been resolved by your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75289472/283366)?

Comment: yes, it solved phil

Comment: it is so weird, if i don't see any error logs from nginx I would never find out the root of the problem because of the limit rate, since the browser says it's 503 and a Cors error