# Error CORS/503 happens when I fetch nginx for the first time

Tags: javascript, nginx, cors

This is related to my previous question [From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75287786/cors-problem-when-i-use-nginx-on-my-server-but-it-completely-fine-when-i-try-to)

So basically what happened is I can't fetch my API for the first time fetch through nginx, the error happened like this:

[image: when i first time fetch the API]

the rest of it is perfectly fine if I only fetch one path from one page, error occurs when I try to fetch more than one path to my API like this:

[image: became cors and 503 error]

That happens when I try to fetch more than one path in the same destination.

What did I miss? Did I do wrong in my nodejs? nginx, or when I try to fetch it? I use React for FE
because all is perfectly fine on all path when the endpoint targeted into public IP+port but an error like this happens when I try to fetch the API from my https+dns with nginx.

This is my nginx configuration:

```
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=400r/m;
    server { root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.xyz www.example.xyz;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000 ; # your app's port
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        #       add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin * ;

                limit_req zone=one;
        }
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.xyz/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.xyz/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

What can I do to fix it? Is it my nginx configuration?

Comment: What do your Nginx error logs say about the 503 response? That error status typically indicates a problem communicating with the proxied service

Comment: is this what u mean? 'HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Mon, 30 Jan 2023 23:55:03 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 608
Connection: keep-alive'

Comment: oh i see, in nginx error logs,

2023/01/31 00:01:50 [error] 28104#28104: *323 limiting requests, excess: 0.201 by zone "one", client: 36.65.254.95, server: example.com, request: "GET /users HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/"
2023/01/31 00:02:20 [error] 28104#28104: *323 limiting requests, excess: 0.234 by zone "one", client: 36.65.254.95, server: example.com, request: "GET /users HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/"

those are

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it, i just found out about burst,
so i just put this line of code

```
limit_req zone=one burst=12 delay=8;
```

in my nginx configurations, i read the explanation from this blogs
https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/
and thanks to [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil). I don't think i would have found the reason if you didn't tell me to check the error log xD